# Jquery .on() 'keyup' function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to give event when pressing keyboard.

Don't know why this does not work. Any help?

```js
$('input').on('keyup', '.aa', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="aa">
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to work? The delegated event handling binding seems incorrect. Unless you have a custom tag called `aa`.

Comment: Use selector`'.aa'` instead of `'aa'`. Voting to close _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @vlaz sorry forgot to put . when giving question. I did on my real code, but still not working.

Comment: @mplungjan  sorry forgot to put . when giving question. I did on my real code, but still not working. And it is not typo question.

Comment: `$('input.aa').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log('hello');
});` -  .aa is not a child of input.

Comment: You're still binding this incorrectly. `$('input')` does not work when the element you're binding is ALSO the one filtered using the second parameter of `.on()`. It needs to be a parent of the selector.

Comment: @vlaz Ah.. Great! You were right. But if there is lots of div parent. I should not use `$('div')`. It will alert alot. So using `$('body')` is correct.

Comment: I mean that it can be ANY parent, as long as the filter selector you're applying is a child to it of any level. So, yes `body` works but it could also be, say `#mainContent` if a div with such ID exists and holds the element(s) with a class of `aa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed to prefix the dot before the *class*.

Also use a static container instead of input. Try `$('body').on('keyup', '.aa', function(){`

```js
$('body').on('keyup', '.aa', function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="aa">
```

Comment: Please do not answer TYPO-type questions

Comment: @mplungjan It was not the typo-type question.

Comment: @Mamun Thanks. Didn't know should use body instead of input

Comment: I see. There was more than one issue. A delegation issue too

Comment: @Junie Any static container - most use $("document") rather than $("body")

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="aa">
```

jQuery:

```
$('.aa').keyup(function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

The `keyup` event above is just a shortcut for `.on( "keyup", handler )`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're absolutely right, I made a mistake and edited my response

Comment: @brooksrelyt Aye I knew how to do with .keyup() function. Was wondering how to handle with .on() function

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is just put the class identified right in the selector

```js
$('input.aa').on('keyup', function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="aa">
```

Comment: @mplungjan sorry dude... Comments arnt answers in my opinion. comments are to get a better understanding. Did not see your comment. Was in the process of posting when you commented most likely.

Comment: The question is not worth answering

Comment: @mplungjan I see what your saying but giving an alternative not a typo-fix